# using two Arduino libraries with the same name together

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have two libraries with the name SimpleTimer
and both of them I needed in my project, so how I can use them together or merge them in one library ?

When I change name of one this error occurs:
**Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.**

Comment: If you're using C++, you can `#include` the headers into different namespaces. It's a hack and it's ugly, but it'll help if the libraries provide their classes in the global namespace

Comment: @SimonC Many libraries will break if you do that. Sadly, if C++ libraries have collisions, that is a non-trivial problem. It's worth a try though.

Comment: I've been very lucky in the past with this approach, especially when it comes to legacy code. I'd say it's worth a try and if it doesn't work, a fork of the library(ies) may be necessary

Comment: which two exactly?

Comment: And why do you think you need them both?

Comment: I tried to change name of one library but still have the same problem

Comment: the libraries are simpleTimer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get a hold of two of the libraries source files and include the source code of those libraries in your project and then change the name from there.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Wong said, if you have them locally then the best solution is to just rename them. However, why would you need both? Is there not another timer package that will work the same?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a situation of including the same library twice.
Just create two timer objects.
Example based on: [http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer/)

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

// Two timer objects
SimpleTimer timerOne;
SimpleTimer timerTwo;

// a function to be executed periodically on timerOne
void repeatMeOne() {
    Serial.print("Uptime timer one(s): ");
    Serial.println(millis() / 1000);
}

// a function to be executed periodically on timerTwo
void repeatMeTwo() {
    Serial.print("Uptime timer two (s): ");
    Serial.println(millis() / 1000);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    timerOne.setInterval(1000, repeatMeOne);
    timerTwo.setInterval(2000, repeatMeTwo);
}

void loop() {
    timerOne.run();
    timerTwo.run();
}
```